# Gradle build error after updating Android Studio to 2.2 Preview 3

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After updating AS from **2.2 Preview *2*** to **2.2 Preview *3***, and updating an AS project to the new format, the follow error is encountered when trying to build & run the app:

> Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task
>   ':app:generateDebugInstantRunAppInfo'.
>
> > File '\app\build\intermediates\bundles\debug\instant-run\AndroidManifest.xml'
> >     specified for property 'mergedManifest' does not exist.

However the above message just points to failure in the prior build processes, where `google-services.json` isn't properly imported, and the following AndroidManifest entry would produce symbol '`google_play_services_version`' not found error after the update:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Additionally all the activity entries and most service entries in AndroidManifest have this error: `'xxxService' is not assignable to 'android.app.Activity/Service'`

Clean Project & Build Project doesn't help, any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Disable Instant Run.
Build and launch app.
Stop app.
Enable Instant Run.
Build and launch app.

I noticed the same error after I took the preview 3 update. The above steps corrected the issue for me.

Comment: This did not work for me, I am using AS 2.2 Preview 4 :(

Comment: Error:A problem was found with the configuration of task :generateDevDebugInstantRunAppInfo'.
App/build/intermediates/bundles/dev/debug/instant-run/AndroidManifest.xml' specified for property 'mergedManifest' does not exist. No such directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the same issue with Preview 4,

1. Enable Instant Run from settings.
2. Delete the App from device/simulator.
3. Clean Project.
4. Rebuild and launch App.

Comment: This did not work for me, I am using AS 2.2 Preview 4 :(

Comment: @pyus13 Often times you have to do the above mentioned steps multiple times. Updated the steps again.